# What is the difference between $this->render() and $this->redirect()

Tags: php, yii

I am new to the Yii framework and I would like to know the difference between `$this->render()` and `$this->redirect()`.
Both can be used to retrieve a given page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like they do quite different things:

- `->redirect($url, ...)`
  [redirect](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#redirect-detail) does a HTTP page redirect. Does not directly render a page.
- `->render($view, ...)`
  [render](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#render-detail)  outputs the named view. Does not terminate the current PHP request.

Answer (score 0):

After the redirect, the browser will request another page that will have its own render() call. With a redirect, you will see the url change in your address bar and a different page. Unless of course you are redirecting to the page that you were already on.

Answer (score 0):

> ->render('$view',...)

this is better used when you want to render same page beacause it's store action means it's cant change browser url.

> ->redirect('$relative_url',..)

this is better to use for show different page because it's change url as well as action.